# R markdown: force a character string into more than 1 lines

Tags: r, string, pdf, r-markdown

I have

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

Below should be in four lines

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
test<-c("This should be in the first line \n This in the second line \n This in the third line \n This in the fourth line")
```
    
`r test`
````

in the PDF `test` is displayed in 1 line. Is it possible to knit the `test` string into 4 lines within Rmarkdown or do I have to preprocess it in R? `\n` does not seem to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escaping acrobatics, use `\\\n`.

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

Below should be in four lines

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
test<-c("This should be in the first line \\\n This in the second line \\\n This in the third line \\\n This in the fourth line")
```
    
`r test`
````

[image]